# keycode for MouseEvent?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, flashdevelop, keycode

So to my understanding, there are keycodes to represent the keystrokes, for example:

```
public function left(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keycode == 65)
    {
       leftKey = true;
    }
}
```

I want to do something similar with this logic and apply it for Mouse Events. I've searched on Google but haven't found much results for Flashdevelop AS3. Would there be a keycode to represent Mouse Events? 
For example:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, move);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

public function down(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.keycode == ?)
}
public function move(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.keycode == ?)
}
public function click(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.keycode == ?)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html

Comment: you mean like the left, middle, or right mouse buttons?  Or if a keyboard key is pressed while clicking?  At any rate, the documentation on this is great.  Just read that and you should see what you need to do.  Come back here if you have a more specific question.

Comment: Because your example doesn't really make sense... how can there be a keycode for a mouse MOVE?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context folks, I want to indicate that whenever I'm left clicking or holding the mouse click, I want to put a condition there, just like the keystroke condition. I don't know what keystroke or to compare mouse click with in order to fulfil a condition.

Comment: Yeah you just use MouseEvent.CLICK or MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN. It's literally what you already posted. Have you tried it? It should work just fine. What isn't working? What is happening that you don't expect or what ain't happening that you do expect?

Comment: Of course you don't need the e.keycode bit. This function won't be getting called *unless* the mouse was clicked or is down or whatever, so why try to check for it again? That's like saying if condition A is true, then check if condition A is true.

Comment: Also, just read the API link that i posted in my comment.  It's all explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fire a mouse event that *has* a listener attached to it, then the function associated with that listener will get called.  Period.  You don't need to then, again, check to see if the mouse event happened.  That's the whole beauty of event listeners.  Just to make sure you get it, I'll post an example.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,mClick);
```

Great. We added a listener to the stage.  Now, any time you click anywhere on the stage, this listener will cause that `mClick` function to get called.  Now we write the `mClick` function.

```
private function mClick(me:MouseEvent):void{
    trace("me.target.x",me.target.x);
    trace("me.target.y",me.target.y);
}
```

`me` is just a variable we chose to represent the event that triggered this function.  `Event` is a class.  A `MouseEvent` is a subclass of `Event`.  So we are saying that `me` is an `Event` of sublcass `MouseEvent` and that this is the expected *input* for this function.  If you were to try to call this function elsewhere in your code it would throw an error saying that this function expected some sort of input.

`me.target` is the *thing* that caused the event to get triggered. In this case it is the mouse, so `me.target.x` will be the x position of the mouse at the time that the mouse was clicked.

That is all there is to it.  You have just confused yourself a little bit by trying to apply a specific solution to a different problem, namely, how to register key presses on a keyboard.  They are handled slightly fundamentally differently.  With a keyboard, we check listen for if the keyboard had *a* key pressed and then in the event handler, we determine *which* key was pressed.  With mouse events we would have a different listener for mouse move, mouse click, left mouse click and middle mouse click.  Since each of those specific events has their own listener, we don't have to evaluate which button was pressed in the handler:

```
public function left(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keycode == 65)
    {
       leftKey = true;
    }
}
```

The `e` is the thing that caused the event.  In this case, the Keyboard key.  Each key has a keycode.  But instead of writing a different listener for every single key on the keyboard, we can just write one listener and one function and then evaluate which key was pressed inside the function.  As stated before, with the mouse, the left mouse button gets its own event listener, so no need (or ability) to check that in the event listener.  There are properties like `ROLL_OVER` and `MOUSE_UP` and `MOUSE_DOWN`.  Look at the documentation for a full list.

Comment: Oh I see. So it happens in real time when I perform the action, there's not really a need to check anything. Thanks again Mr. Davis!!

Comment: Right again @Neal Davis :)